# CTC loss goes down and stops

Tags: python, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, pytorch

I’m trying to train a captcha recognition model. Model details are resnet pretrained CNN layers + Bidirectional LSTM + Fully Connected. It reached 90% sequence accuracy on captcha generated by python library [captcha](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/captcha/0.1.1). The problem is that these generated captcha seems to have similary location of each character. When I randomly add spaces between characters, the model does not work any more. So I wonder is LSTM learning segmentation during learning? Then I try to use CTC loss. At first, loss goes down pretty quick. But it stays at about 16 without significant drop later. I tried different layers of LSTM, different number of units. 2 Layers of LSTM reach lower loss, but still not converging. 3 layers are just like 2 layers. The loss curve:

[image]

```python
#encoding:utf8
import os
import sys
import torch
import warpctc_pytorch
import traceback

import torchvision
from torch import nn, autograd, FloatTensor, optim
from torch.nn import functional as F
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import MultiStepLR
from tensorboard import SummaryWriter
from pprint import pprint

from net.utils import decoder

from logging import getLogger, StreamHandler
logger = getLogger(__name__)
handler = StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
logger.addHandler(handler)

from dataset_util.utils import id_to_character
from dataset_util.transform import rescale, normalizer
from config.config import MAX_CAPTCHA_LENGTH, TENSORBOARD_LOG_PATH, MODEL_PATH


class CNN_RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, lstm_bidirectional=True, use_ctc=True, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CNN_RNN, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        model_conv = torchvision.models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
        for param in model_conv.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False

        modules = list(model_conv.children())[:-1]  # delete the last fc layer.
        for param in modules[8].parameters():
            param.requires_grad = True

        self.resnet = nn.Sequential(*modules)            # CNN with fixed parameters from resnet as feature extractor
        self.lstm_input_size = 512 * 2 * 2
        self.lstm_hidden_state_size = 512
        self.lstm_num_layers = 2
        self.chracter_space_length = 64
        self._lstm_bidirectional = lstm_bidirectional
        self._use_ctc = use_ctc
        if use_ctc:
            self._max_captcha_length = int(MAX_CAPTCHA_LENGTH * 2)
        else:
            self._max_captcha_length = MAX_CAPTCHA_LENGTH

        if lstm_bidirectional:
            self.lstm_hidden_state_size = self.lstm_hidden_state_size * 2           # so that hidden size for one direction in bidirection lstm is the same as vanilla lstm
            self.lstm = self.lstm = nn.LSTM(self.lstm_input_size, self.lstm_hidden_state_size // 2, dropout=0.5, bidirectional=True, num_layers=self.lstm_num_layers)
        else:
            self.lstm = nn.LSTM(self.lstm_input_size, self.lstm_hidden_state_size, dropout=0.5, bidirectional=False, num_layers=self.lstm_num_layers)  # dropout doen't work for one layer lstm

        self.ouput_to_tag = nn.Linear(self.lstm_hidden_state_size, self.chracter_space_length)
        self.tensorboard_writer = SummaryWriter(TENSORBOARD_LOG_PATH)
        # self.dropout_lstm = nn.Dropout()


    def init_hidden_status(self, batch_size):
        if self._lstm_bidirectional:
            self.hidden = (autograd.Variable(torch.zeros((self.lstm_num_layers * 2, batch_size, self.lstm_hidden_state_size // 2))),
                           autograd.Variable(torch.zeros((self.lstm_num_layers * 2, batch_size, self.lstm_hidden_state_size // 2)))) # number of layers, batch size, hidden dimention
        else:
            self.hidden = (autograd.Variable(torch.zeros((self.lstm_num_layers, batch_size, self.lstm_hidden_state_size))),
                           autograd.Variable(torch.zeros((self.lstm_num_layers, batch_size, self.lstm_hidden_state_size)))) # number of layers, batch size, hidden dimention


    def forward(self, image):
        '''
        :param image:  # batch_size, CHANNEL, HEIGHT, WIDTH
        :return:
        '''
        features = self.resnet(image)                 # [batch_size, 512, 2, 2]
        batch_size = image.shape[0]
        features = [features.view(batch_size, -1) for i in range(self._max_captcha_length)]
        features = torch.stack(features)
        self.init_hidden_status(batch_size)
        output, hidden = self.lstm(features, self.hidden)
        # output = self.dropout_lstm(output)
        tag_space = self.ouput_to_tag(output.view(-1, output.size(2)))      # [MAX_CAPTCHA_LENGTH * BATCH_SIZE, CHARACTER_SPACE_LENGTH]
        tag_space = tag_space.view(self._max_captcha_length, batch_size, -1)

        if not self._use_ctc:
            tag_score = F.log_softmax(tag_space, dim=2)             # [MAX_CAPTCHA_LENGTH, BATCH_SIZE, CHARACTER_SPACE_LENGTH]
        else:
            tag_score = tag_space

        return tag_score


    def train_net(self, data_loader, eval_data_loader=None, learning_rate=0.008, epoch_num=400):
        try:
            if self._use_ctc:
                loss_function = warpctc_pytorch.warp_ctc.CTCLoss()
            else:
                loss_function = nn.NLLLoss()

            # optimizer = optim.SGD(filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, self.parameters()), momentum=0.9, lr=learning_rate)
            # optimizer = MultiStepLR(optimizer, milestones=[10,15], gamma=0.5)

            # optimizer = optim.Adadelta(filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, self.parameters()))
            optimizer = optim.Adam(filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, self.parameters()))
            self.tensorboard_writer.add_scalar("learning_rate", learning_rate)

            tensorbard_global_step=0
            if os.path.exists(os.path.join(TENSORBOARD_LOG_PATH, "resume_step")):
                with open(os.path.join(TENSORBOARD_LOG_PATH, "resume_step"), "r") as file_handler:
                    tensorbard_global_step = int(file_handler.read()) + 1

            for epoch_index, epoch in enumerate(range(epoch_num)):
                for index, sample in enumerate(data_loader):
                    optimizer.zero_grad()
                    input_image = autograd.Variable(sample["image"])        # batch_size, 3, 255, 255
                    tag_score = self.forward(input_image)

                    if self._use_ctc:
                        tag_score, target, tag_score_sizes, target_sizes = self._loss_preprocess_ctc(tag_score, sample)
                        loss = loss_function(tag_score, target, tag_score_sizes, target_sizes)
                        loss = loss / tag_score.size(1)

                    else:
                        target = sample["padded_label_idx"]
                        tag_score, target = self._loss_preprocess(tag_score, target)
                        loss = loss_function(tag_score, target)

                    print("Training loss: {}".format(float(loss)))
                    self.tensorboard_writer.add_scalar("training_loss", float(loss), tensorbard_global_step)
                    loss.backward()
                    optimizer.step()

                    if index % 250 == 0:
                        print(u"Processing batch: {} of {}, epoch: {}".format(index, len(data_loader), epoch_index))
                        self.evaluate(eval_data_loader, loss_function, tensorbard_global_step)

                    tensorbard_global_step += 1

                self.save_model(MODEL_PATH + "_epoch_{}".format(epoch_index))

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Exit for KeyboardInterrupt, save model")
            self.save_model(MODEL_PATH)

            with open(os.path.join(TENSORBOARD_LOG_PATH, "resume_step"), "w") as file_handler:
                file_handler.write(str(tensorbard_global_step))

        except Exception as excp:
            logger.error(str(excp))
            logger.error(traceback.format_exc())


    def predict(self, image):
        # TODO ctc version
        '''
        :param image: [batch_size, channel, height, width]
        :return:
        '''
        tag_score = self.forward(image)
        # TODO ctc
        # if self._use_ctc:
        #     tag_score = F.softmax(tag_score, dim=-1)
        #     decoder.decode(tag_score)

        confidence_log_probability, indexes = tag_score.max(2)

        predicted_labels = []
        for batch_index in range(indexes.size(1)):
            label = ""
            for character_index in range(self._max_captcha_length):
                if int(indexes[character_index, batch_index]) != 1:
                    label += id_to_character[int(indexes[character_index, batch_index])]
            predicted_labels.append(label)

        return predicted_labels, tag_score


    def predict_pil_image(self, pil_image):
        try:
            self.eval()
            processed_image = normalizer(rescale({"image": pil_image}))["image"].view(1, 3, 255, 255)
            result, tag_score = self.predict(processed_image)
            self.train()

        except Exception as excp:
            logger.error(str(excp))
            logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
            return [""], None

        return result, tag_score


    def evaluate(self, eval_dataloader, loss_function, step=0):
        total = 0
        sequence_correct = 0
        character_correct = 0
        character_total = 0
        loss_total = 0
        batch_size = eval_data_loader.batch_size
        true_predicted = {}
        self.eval()
        for sample in eval_dataloader:
            total += batch_size
            input_images = sample["image"]
            predicted_labels, tag_score = self.predict(input_images)

            for predicted, true_label in zip(predicted_labels, sample["label"]):
                if predicted == true_label:                  # dataloader is making label a list, use batch_size=1
                    sequence_correct += 1

                for index, true_character in enumerate(true_label):
                    character_total += 1
                    if index < len(predicted) and predicted[index] == true_character:
                        character_correct += 1

                true_predicted[true_label] = predicted

            if self._use_ctc:
                tag_score, target, tag_score_sizes, target_sizes = self._loss_preprocess_ctc(tag_score, sample)
                loss_total += float(loss_function(tag_score, target, tag_score_sizes, target_sizes) / batch_size)

            else:
                tag_score, target = self._loss_preprocess(tag_score, sample["padded_label_idx"])
                loss_total += float(loss_function(tag_score, target))  # averaged over batch index

        print("True captcha to predicted captcha: ")
        pprint(true_predicted)
        self.tensorboard_writer.add_text("eval_ture_to_predicted", str(true_predicted), global_step=step)

        accuracy = float(sequence_correct) / total
        avg_loss = float(loss_total) / (total / batch_size)
        character_accuracy = float(character_correct) / character_total
        self.tensorboard_writer.add_scalar("eval_sequence_accuracy", accuracy, global_step=step)
        self.tensorboard_writer.add_scalar("eval_character_accuracy", character_accuracy, global_step=step)
        self.tensorboard_writer.add_scalar("eval_loss", avg_loss, global_step=step)
        self.zero_grad()
        self.train()


    def _loss_preprocess(self, tag_score, target):
        '''
        :param tag_score:  value return by self.forward
        :param target:     sample["padded_label_idx"]
        :return:           (processed_tag_score, processed_target)  ready for NLLoss function
        '''
        target = target.transpose(0, 1)
        target = target.contiguous()
        target = target.view(target.size(0) * target.size(1))
        tag_score = tag_score.view(-1, self.chracter_space_length)

        return tag_score, target


    def _loss_preprocess_ctc(self, tag_score, sample):
        target_2d = [
            [int(ele) for ele in sample["padded_label_idx"][row, :] if int(ele) != 0 and int(ele) != 1]
            for row in range(sample["padded_label_idx"].size(0))]
        target = []
        for ele in target_2d:
            target.extend(ele)
        target = autograd.Variable(torch.IntTensor(target))

        # tag_score = F.softmax(F.sigmoid(tag_score), dim=-1)
        tag_score_sizes = autograd.Variable(torch.IntTensor([self._max_captcha_length] * tag_score.size(1)))
        target_sizes = autograd.Variable(sample["captcha_length"].int())

        return tag_score, target, tag_score_sizes, target_sizes


    # def visualize_graph(self, dataset):
    #     '''Since pytorch use dynamic graph, an input is required to visualize graph in tensorboard'''
    #     # warning: Do not run this, the graph is too large to visualize...
    #     sample = dataset[0]
    #     input_image = autograd.Variable(sample["image"].view(1, 3, 255, 255))
    #     tag_score = self.forward(input_image)
    #     self.tensorboard_writer.add_graph(self, tag_score)


    def save_model(self, model_path):
        self.tensorboard_writer.close()
        self.tensorboard_writer = None          # can't be pickled
        torch.save(self, model_path)
        self.tensorboard_writer = SummaryWriter(TENSORBOARD_LOG_PATH)


    @classmethod
    def load_model(cls, model_path=MODEL_PATH, *args, **kwargs):
        net = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        if os.path.exists(model_path):
            model = torch.load(model_path)
            if model:
                model.tensorboard_writer = SummaryWriter(TENSORBOARD_LOG_PATH)
                net = model

        return net


    def __del__(self):
        if self.tensorboard_writer:
            self.tensorboard_writer.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from dataset_util.dataset import dataset, eval_dataset
    data_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True)
    eval_data_loader = DataLoader(eval_dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True)

    net = CNN_RNN.load_model()

    net.train_net(data_loader, eval_data_loader=eval_data_loader)
    # net.predict(dataset[0]["image"].view(1, 3, 255, 255))

    # predict_pil_image test code
    # from config.config import IMAGE_PATHS
    # import glob
    # from PIL import Image
    #
    # image_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(IMAGE_PATHS.get("EVAL"), "*.png"))
    # for image_path in image_paths:
    #     pil_image = Image.open(image_path)
    #     predicted, score = net.predict_pil_image(pil_image)
    #     print("True value: {}, predicted: {}".format(os.path.split(image_path)[1], predicted))

    print("Done")
```

The above codes are main part. If you need other components that makes it running, leave a comment. Got stuck here for quite long. Any advice for training crnn + ctc is appreciated.

Comment: can you give show some samples what the network outputs when you feed an image? Given an image, does it output (1) nonsense or (2) an empty string? Further, can you summarize your code (its pretty long), e.g. which optimizer do you use?

Comment: I haven't got Beam Search Decoder working. According to characters with the most high probability each sequence step, the model predicts empty string at first, then 1 character, 2 characters. But accross traning images, it predicts the same character. I'm using Adam with pytorch default parameter. An intersting thing I notice is that the training loss variance becomes larger and larger during training till the eval loss stops decreasing. The code above is feeding images to resnet pretrained CNN layers, then Bidirectional LSTM, Fully Connected Layer, finally CTC loss.

Comment: feed the same image all the time and check if the loss gets zero in this simple case.
Try other learning rates and check if this makes a difference.
For decoding, you can use best path decoding, which is simple and fast: get most probable character per time-step, remove duplicate characters, remove blanks. 
Looking at the decoded output can really help when debugging such systems.

Comment: 1 image, 3 images, 5 images all work. The same kind of large loss variance happen too. Probably it is a problem of optimizer and hyperparameters. I'll try different optimizer and hyperparameters when loss stops decreasing. Thanks, I'll notice you if anything new happen.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I'll try the following comment by patapouf_ai. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I've been training with ctc loss and encountered the same problem. I know this is a rather late answer but hopefully it'll help someone else who's researching on this. After trial and error and a lot of research there are a few things that's worth knowing when it comes to training with ctc (if your model is set up correctly):

1. The quickest way for the model to lower cost is to predict only blanks. This is  noted in a few papers and blogs: see http://www.tbluche.com/ctc_and_blank.html
2. The model learns to predict only blanks first, then it starts picking up on the error signal in regards to the correct underlying labels. This is also explained in the above link. In practice, I noticed that my model starts to learn the real underlying labels/targets after a couple hundred epochs and the loss starts decreasing dramatically again. Similar to what is shown for the toy example here: https://thomasmesnard.github.io/files/CTC_Poster_Mesnard_Auvolat.pdf
3. These parameters have a great impact on whether your model converges or not - learning rate, batch size and epoch number.

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot! Appreciate the response.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few questions, so I will try to answer them one by one.

**First, why does adding spaces to the captcha break the model?**

A neural network learns to deal with the data it is trained on. If you change the distribution of the data (by for example adding spaces between characters) there is no guarantee that the network will generalize. As you hint at in your question. It is possible that the captchas you train on always have the characters in the same positions, or at the same distance from one another, thus your model learns that and learns to exploit this by looking in those positions. If you want your network to generalize a specific scenario, you should explicitly train on that scenario. So in your case, you should add random spaces also during training.

**Second, why does the loss not go below 16?**

Clearly, from the fact that your training loss is also stalled at 16 (like your validation loss), the problem is that your model simply doesn't have the capacity to deal with the complexity of the problem. In other words, your model is underfitting.  You had the correct reflex to try to increase the capacity of your network. You tried to increase the capacity of the LSTM and it didn't help. Thus, the next logical step is that the convolution part of your network is not powerful enough. So here are a few things that you might want to try, from most likely to succeed in my opinion to least likely:

1. **Make convnet trainable:** I notice that you are using a pretrained convnet and that you are not fine-tuning the weights of that convnet. That could be a problem. Whatever your convnet was trained on, it might not develop the required features to deal with captchas. You should try learning the weights of the convnet too, in order to develop useful features for captchas.
2. **Use deeper convnet:** This is the naive thing to do. Your convnet doesn't have good enough features, try a more powerful deeper one. (But you should definitely use this only after you've made the convnet trainable).

Comment: Thanks! Once I realized the space issue, I've been trying to train my model on new dataset with randomly added spaces. I've read about reports doing this captcha recognition using similar layers and units of LSTM and CTC. So I did not think too much about its capacity. CNN capacity could be a problem. I'll try training different num of layers of CNN.

Comment: Make sure, that you train your CNN too. Add  `param.requires_grad = True` to more layers of your CNN.

Comment: Tried making CNN trainable, nothing really changed. I think this is a problem caused by CTC. Refer to: [github issue](https://github.com/Lasagne/Recipes/issues/6). It seems quite some people get stuck in such situation.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, training RNN model with CTC loss is not an EASY task. The model may not converge at all if the training is not carefully setup-ed. Here are my suggestions:

1. Check the CTC loss output along training. For a model would converge, the CTC loss at each batch **fluctuates** notably. If you observed that the CTC loss shrinks almost **monotonically** to a stable value, then the model is most likely stuck at a local minima
2. Use short samples to **pretrain** your model. Though we have advanced RNN strucures like `LSTM` and `GRU`, it's still hard to back-propagate the RNN for long steps.
3. Enlarge sample variety. You can even add artificial samples to help your model **escape** from local minima.

F.Y.I., we've just open-sourced a new deep learning framework [Dandelion](https://github.com/david-leon/Dandelion) which has built-in CTC objective, and interface pretty much like pytorch. You can try your model with Dandelion and compare it with your current implementation.